# Cannot install Android APK from Crashlytics Beta

Tags: android, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta, fabric-beta

After uploading a new build to Crashlytics Beta, users are not able to install

Here's what's happening:

1. User receives an email notification with the latest build
2. Taps "Check it out", which opens Beta by Crashlytics
3. Clicking "Install Update" results in an error "App not installed".  There are no additional details

This is happening on both Samsung S8, Android 8.0.0 and Pixel 2, Android 9

I tried uninstalling the existing app on the phone but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I started getting this today.  My colleague's build reported this error and after merging his code, my build is now reporting the same.  I can install directly from Android Studio, but not from Fabric Beta.  From logcat, I do see an error "PackageManager: result of install: -15{162457065}" but I cannot find this code in any of the documentation.

Comment: @mobibob Is this happening on all devices?

Comment: Same bug on the same phone, Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 9. Did you manage to fix it ?

Comment: @hardworker Nope.  I suspect it's related to Fabric sunsetting...

Answer (score 8):

You have to disable **Google Play Protect** from the PlayStore App and enable it again after the installation has succeeded.

Comment: This felt real good, but did not resolve the -15 result code.  Additional, information that was not apparent yesterday.  I am building for different environments and my SIT build installs, but my UAT build does not install (from Fabric email invite).  This only started happening this week and my Android did update over the holiday: Android 8.0.0; Samsung Experience 9.0; Kernel version: 4.9.65-14787400.

Comment: This didn't work, I still get "App not installed" after attempting installation.

Comment: Usually the "App not installed" is caused by: (1) Google Play Protect enabled while installing APK manually, (2) APK is not signed with a valid (NON debug) Certificate or (3) not supported Signin method (the "V1" and "V2" options of Android Studio dialog when ready to build a Release APK)

Answer (score 2):

Found that the app gets insatlled only if its a released version. I was trying to install on Samsung SM-G975

Comment: Running the app via AndroidStudio would install it but when I tried to install the apk by opening the file on a device it would fail. I tried the release version and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Device reboot did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems, both time-stamp related.

- my npm token (.npmrc) had expired on 12/24/2018 and my build-script shell uses npm
- a build tool that is used "node-jq" made a change 12/27/2018 and its binary-building function has a dependency that is not in my environment and not declared in the project's dependencies.  (I downgraded rather than resolve the move-forward solution).

My build script shell (for cordova build) does a horrible job of distinguishing between warnings, errors (that get fixed) and fatal errors.  Therefore, it built to completion but with a bogus image.  There must have been enough to satisfy Gradle but not enough to satisfy Fabric.

As for the Google Play Protect, I will keep that in mind for future issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just manage to solve this issue with an update to my Fabric plugin for Android Studio.

On the top menu click Android Studio -> Check for Updates...

Answer (score 0):

I had got this problem too. In my case one of the resources file was in main and release directory (src->main and src->release). Then I moved it from main to debug (src->debug) and build from Beta began to install successfully.
It's important that all files wasn't spoiled and was in right places.